# Path.Combine acting unexpectedly when using in combination with Server.MapPath

Tags: c#, path

Here are the simple two lines of code:

```
public static void RemoveCoverImageForProduct(int productId)
{
    using (var productRepository = new EfProductRepository())
    {
        var product = productRepository.FindById(productId);
        var coverFolderPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"~/");
        var filePath = Path.Combine(coverFolderPath, product.CoverImagePath);
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
            File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

---

`Server.MapPath()` is returning:

```
C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp.WebUI\
```

`product.CoverImagePath` is returning:

```
/Public/products/buscar.jpg
```

The result of running Path.Combine on both of them, meaning the value of `filePath` after running is:

```
/Public/products/buscar.jpg
```

What I'm expecting is this:

```
C:\Users\Sergio\Desktop\MyApp\MyApp.WebUI\Public\products\buscar.jpg
```

---

Any ideas why this isn't working as I expect it to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rules for the second argument of `Path.Combine` are

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator character. **If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.**

The slash in `product.CoverImagePath` is a root, which is why `Path.Combine` is returning

```
/Public/products/buscar.jpg
```

Assuming you know that it begins with a slash, you can remove it and pass that into `Path.Combine`:

```
var filePath = Path.Combine(coverFolderPath, product.CoverImagePath.Substring(1));
```

If you're unsure, use a conditional:

```
var relativeFilename = Path.IsPathRooted(product.CoverImagePath) 
    ? product.CoverImagePath.Substring(1)
    : product.CoverImagePath;
var filePath = Path.Combine(coverFolderPath, relativeFilename);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's all in the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyy7a5kt.aspx):

> If path2 does not include a root (for example, if path2 does not start
>   with a separator character or a drive specification), the result is a
>   concatenation of the two paths, with an intervening separator
>   character. **If path2 includes a root, path2 is returned.**

A slash ('/') is a separator character, hence you get back the path `/Public/products/buscar.jpg` you passed in.